# Gitlab CI/CD ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user

Tags: docker, gitlab, mariadb

I'm trying to get a gitlab CI/CD pipeline set up.  One of the things the pipeline needs to do is run unit and integration tests.  So I need a mariadb set up.  I created a docker file and built an image that should have an environment variable set so a mysql user will be created called chris and have a password called chris.  Then, I push the docker image up to amazon ECR.  In my gitlab-ci.yml file the image used is the one I pushed to amazon ECR.  The problem I'm having is that user chris is not getting access, BUT user root works fine.  What do I need to add to my docker file so that I can use user chris and not root?

dockerfile

```
FROM mariadb:latest

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD "chris"
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE "testingdb"
ENV MYSQL_USER "chris"
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD "chris"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install vim

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: XXXXXX.XXXXX.amazonaws.com/chris_mariadb:latest

services:
  - mariadb

variables:
  # Configure mysql environment variables (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: "testingdb"
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "chris"
  Host: mysql
  User: chris
  Password: chris

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ls
    - mysql --user=chris --password=chris --host=localhost --port=3306 --database=testingdb --protocol=TCP --batch --local-infile < ./data/schema.sql
```

Error

```
$ mysql --user=chris --password=chris --host=localhost --port=3306 --database=testingdb --protocol=TCP --batch --local-infile < ./data/schema.sql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'chris'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

Any help would be great.  I know I probably don't need the variables in my gitlab-ci.yml because I'm not using a mysql runner, but I got desperate and am trying whatever I can for this to work.  I tried running the image as a container, went in and granted all privileges to chris with the wildcard and chris@127.0.0.1, and push those changes up to ECR, but that didn't change anything.    Also, this works correctly when user=root and password=chris.  I also get errors when I don't use TCP and try to use a sock, so I don't want to go down that route again unless it is super recommended.

Comment: try changing your user from chris to chris@127.0.0.1 and try again

Answer (score 0):

Add environment variable MYSQL_USER:"chris" at your gitlab-ci.yml.

Answer (score 0):

this was not an easy one to debug for us, we had a `....$F....` in the randomly-generated database password that was stored in the gitlab CI variables, and gitlab was trying to replace that with a variable.

Essentially altering the password, and this caused the same issue